# How to create a simple visitors' tag using python

Tags: python, django, opencv, webcam

I need a clue regarding this task.
I was given a project on creating a simple tag to identify visitors within our school premises.

It’s like an ID card that displays the names, purpose of visit and the image of the visitor. The image will be captured using a webcam and will be printed along with the visitor’s information. The print will be similar to an ID card and the visitor will use it as a tag when he’s in our school’s premises.
Because of my familiarity with python, I chose to use either Django (web platform) of Tkinter (desktop). I’m using OpenCV to capture the image.
I’m on the right track? If no, is there any simpler yet a better way of approaching the problem?
Thank you.

It will appear like this:
[visitors' tag](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArIp7wTbE3b5itAAYXmQfJ3XcxJ1Rg)!

Comment: I would go with a qr code approach, instead OpenCV.

Comment: Thank you @Stargazer Can you elaborate more on using qr code?

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create blank card
bg = np.zeros((500,800,3), np.uint8)
bg[:,:,:] = 255,255,255

# Make a rectangle
x,y,w,h = 50,50,700,100
cv2.rectangle(bg, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (234,234,234), cv2.FILLED)

# Put some text
org, font, scale, color, thick = (70,120), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 0, 1
cv2.putText(bg, "Visitor's Pass", org, font, scale, color, thick)

# Put an image
lena = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/lenna.png')
x,y,w,h = 550,180,200,260
bg[y:y+h, x:x+w] = cv2.resize(lena, (w,h))

# Show image
cv2.imshow('img', bg)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: card]